# diff --git unknown option

Tags: git, diff, options

when I try to run

```
diff --git a/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c b/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c
```

I get unknown option (I have installed git via `apt-get install git`)

Answer (score 18):

Either use

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

or

```
git diff branch/commit1 branch/commit2
```

More on git diff at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html

I am not aware of any `--git` option however for `diff` and the man page doesn't show it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, when you run a recursive diff between two directories, for each file diff includes a diff command showing you what it is doing for each file.  For example:

```
$ diff -ru a b
diff -ru a/file b/file
--- a/file  2015-07-17 01:06:14.078875805 -0700
+++ b/file  2015-07-17 01:06:21.969077076 -0700
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hello
+goodbye
```

Git wants to produce patches in the same format, so each file must be preceded by a line starting "`diff`...".  But since git is using it's own internal diff implementation, to make it clear to people reading the output what they are looking at, git adds the imaginary flag `--git`.

In reality, if you want to use git to diff two files or directories in the file system, you can run:

```
git diff --no-index a b
```

(The `--no-index` flag says to ignore any git repository you are in.  That option can be omitted if you are not in a git repository.)  Git produces output in the "unidiff" format.  If you want to approximate that with the system diff command, you can use `diff -ru a b`.  (The `-u` flag selects unidiff format, while the `-r` recurses into directories.)

Answer (score 2):

The real truth is that git is displaying a fake command.

```
$ git diff drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c
diff --git a/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c b/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c
index 286bfoo..14a8foo 100644
--- a/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c
+++ b/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c
```